# What are the benefits of putting jQuery references in Masterpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm currently developing a website with ASP.NET and I always check its performance through Firebug...

Now, my question is,

is it better to put all referencing jquery references in Masterpage?
(Reference all first)

or is it better to put specific jquery reference to a specific Content Page?
(Reference specific only)

Thank you!

Comment: ask yourself which of these solution is more mantainable and which one will make possible make less changes in future (e.g. if you upgrade the library version and change source)

Answer (score 3):

I would think it's best to put your stylesheets in the master page, as long as they are site-wide styles. You should also think about compressing them into one download, so you reduce HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

Maintainance-wise, I would put **each reference where it belongs**, depending on the scope of your jquery-referencing object.

For instance, if it's something to do with, say, the main navigation, that's present on all rendered pages, and therefore certainly in your master page, then you have better have your `$("#navBar")` close to your `<div id="navBar">...</div>`, i.e. on your MasterPage.

If on the other hand it's something related to a specific content page, let's say that shiny carousel (and its specific jQuery plugin) you need on your homepage, you have better have `$('myCarousel').carousel(2);` close to you `<div id="carousel">`, i.e. on your HomePage.aspx content page.

And while you're at dispatching stuff to where they belong, if you can tell for sure that carousel plugin is only required on your homepage, you have better include the plugin on your HomePage.aspx content page only.

Not only will you ease your maintainance, but you will also **get benefits performance-wise**, as you will be more likely to be initializing variables only when they are used, therefore puting a little bit less memory overhead on the browser. Same stuff about loading plugin-related resources (you may not want each and every page load bloated because your master links to every stuff required *somewhere* on your site).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, I would encourage you to identify any libraries or plugins which you would be using on multiple pages and include them in a place which will automatically put them within those pages.

For maintainability, I usually mash/minify all of my third-party libraries (such as jQuery, jQuery-UI, Backbone, etc) into a single JS file, along with any plugins for them which I know I will be using throughout the site. The downside to doing this is that you may have one very large JS file which loads the first time the user loads the page - the upside: client-side cache that file, and the user doesn't have to load it again.

The general rule of thumb is: minify the number of bytes that the user has to download, and minify the number of HTTP requests which the user has to make throughout your site. So - by compressing these kinds of files into a single download, and letting it exist on every page with the same URL - you can have a single request which generally gets a 302 response and no download. This is far better than having 5 different plugins which are loaded on different pages, each of which makes a separate HTTP call - even if those calls all receive 302 responses.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a proper Approach to referencing jquery references on Content Page.

Once give jquery references on Master Page and use them on all content Pages. It is, Proper and Optimized approach.